# Required tag colors have changed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, meta

Notice the comparison between the first screenshot (from a question loaded a few days back) and the second screenshot (from a question loaded today).

> [image]

vs.

> [image]

I don't believe this was intentional (likely related to [some of the recent refactorings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278005/237685)). If this wasn't intentional, can the tag colors be changed back to the original styling?

Comment: I like how it looks now, the required ones have more contrast.

Comment: Can you exactly describe what is bothering you, maybe with some red-circles and how it is affecting you in the actual use of the site features?

Comment: [tag:status-better-this-way]

Comment: They look even better now that borders have been restored to the required and status tags!

Comment: Would you like to keep the darker background then? Or revert it to the previous color?

Comment: Personally I like the previous way better @Hynes, but apparently not everyone agrees with that, as shown above. :)